# Working out the number of emojis in each dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji

Text

0    me así se  ds  hello ‍

1    me así se  ds  hello

2    me así se  ds

3    me así

I want to add a column to my dataframe (df), above, called 'Emoji Count' based on the number of emojis in each row.

For instance, the first row would have a count of 7 as there are 7 emojis in this row.

I understand that to create a new column based on information in the "Text" column I would enter:

```
df["Emoji Count"] = df["Text].....
```

I was able to create a function that counts the number of emojis but I wasn't able to apply this to my dataframe:

```
def split_count(info):

    emoji_list = []
    data = regex.findall(r'\X', info)
    for word in data:
        if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):
            emoji_list.append(word)

    return len(emoji_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
df["Emoji Count"] = df.Text.apply(split_count)
```

or

```
df["Emoji Count"] = df['Text'].apply(split_count)
```

This will apply your function to each cell, and assign the result back to the Emoji Count column.

Answer (score 1):

Manually specified the dataframe to hold emoji's, then simplified your `split_count(info)` function and applied it to the dataframe in order to create the new `"Emoji Count"` column:

```
import pandas as pd
import emoji
import re

e_1 = emoji.emojize(":thinking_face:")
e_2 = emoji.emojize(":see-no-evil_monkey:")
e_3 = emoji.emojize(":relieved_face:")
e_4 = emoji.emojize(":two_hearts:")
e_5 = emoji.emojize(":two_women_holding_hands:")
e_6 = emoji.emojize(":bikini:")
e_7 = emoji.emojize(":woman_student_medium-dark_skin_tone:")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [f"{e_1}{e_2} me así se {e_3} ds {e_4}{e_5}{e_6} hello {e_7}"],
        [f"{e_1}{e_2} me así se {e_3} ds {e_4}{e_5}{e_6} hello"],
        [f"{e_1}{e_2} me así se {e_3} ds"],
        [f"{e_1}{e_2} me así"],
    ],
    columns=["Text"],
)


def split_count(info):
    return len([c for c in info if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI])


df["Emoji Count"] = df["Text"].apply(split_count)
print(df)
```

Returning:

```
                                 Text       Emoji Count
0   me así se  ds  hello ‍              7
1   me así se  ds  hello                 6
2   me así se  ds                             3
3   me así                                     2
```